# Strawberry smoothie tastes grassy?

Tags: flavor, smoothie, strawberries

I've been making enjoyable strawberries at home. However, recently, I used some different strawberries. The new strawberries are bigger, less sweet and a lot less sour, so I'm putting in more strawberries than before. Everything else is the same as usual, with ice, sugar, and milk.

The smoothies, after the change in strawberries, have had a grassy taste & smell, hinting of grass and dirt. The strawberries should be clean and have their stems cut off. The grassy taste goes down with extra ice, but so does the sweetness.

How can I make my strawberry smoothy taste less grassy? (with the new strawberries)

Comment: Usually when I think something tastes a bit like dirt, it's a little moldy. Hopefully this isn't what's causing it for you. Larger strawberries tend not to have as much flavor as smaller ones, but this doesn't help you with your problem. https://www.npr.org/2012/05/17/152944880/bigger-means-better-not-with-strawberries

Comment: Maybe they are just not good, or not ripe enough ?

Answer (score 1):

How do the strawberries smell? If they don't have a strong strawberry smell, you won't be able to squeeze any more strawberry taste out of them. You can try adding a strawberry extract to add more strawberry flavor; maybe start with 1/4 teaspoon.